# RallyDev : Using the search function with list of defects and user stories

Tags: rally

I'd like to do something simple like input in the search box "de123, de122, de145, us234" then have a search result with the items so I can easily manage them.

Is there a way to do this? I used to work like this in bugzilla, I could even do mass edit after my search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you can get to this is probably adding a custom grid app to your dashboard and setting the query in the settings to be what you're looking for:

```
((FormattedID = DE123) OR (FormattedID = DE122))
```

You can inline edit and bulk edit the matching results in the grid.

Comment: I ended up with a big ass query matching what you proposed. Firefox crashed because of the javascript overload... Chrome was abel to cope with the query tho.  Thanks!

Comment: I couldn't find any custom grid that would work... but the "Custom List" app worked. It has other limitations but got the job done.

Comment: One significant "gotcha" with this method - if you have a list of IDs which are a mix of DE and US types, Rally will mix them up. For instance, if you have a `DE1234` in your query, but you tell it to look for user stories, it will find & include `US1234` if it exists! So, beware.

Comment: "Custom List 2" app is a better UI overall but still has that same gotcha